# let $f:X \rightarrow Y$ be such that $f^{-1}(y)$ is a countable set for each $y \in Y$. Supposed Y is countable. Show X is countable.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

let $f:X \rightarrow Y$ be such that $f^{-1}(y)$ is a countable set for each $y \in Y$. Supposed Y is countable. Show X is countable.

$\cup f^{-1}(y)$ is countable since it is a countable union of countable sets.

This shows some subset of X is countable. It doesn't show that X is countable, so how can I fix that?

Comment: _Which_ subset of $X$ is $\bigcup f^{-1}(y)$?

Comment: I have no idea.

Comment: Definition time. What is $f^{-1}(y)$ for $y\in Y$?

Comment: $\cup f^{-1}(y)=X$. Don't know how I missed that. thanks

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** Note that the domain of $f$ is $X$.

Comment: if f is a bijection that would solve the problem, but f isn't given to be a bijection so the inverse is a subset of X but not necessarily all of X. correct?

Comment: You're overthinking this.

Comment: $\cup f^{-1}(y)=X$. Don't know how I missed that. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Note that for any $x\in X$ we have $f(x)=y\in Y$, so $x\in f^{-1}(y)$.

Can you tell what $\bigcup\limits_{y\in Y} f^{-1}(y)$ is now?